# Android kotlin WorkManger doesn't return Worker.Result.FAILURE

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I'm using lates WorkManger Kotlin library '1.0.0-alpha09'.
Sometimes `doWork()` with returning `Worker.Result.FAILURE` status is not received at `WorkContinuation.getStatuses()`.

And the worst part is that I don't get why sometimes it isn't receiving status.

```
fun WorkContinuation.observeStatus(): WorkContinuation {
        statuses.observeForever {
          // status should come here but sometimes it doesn't
        }
        return this
    }


final override fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            // do some work (retrofit network request)
            Worker.Result.SUCCESS

        } catch (error: Throwable) {
            // this status is not receiving by LiveData observer sometimes
            Worker.Result.FAILURE
        }
```

Comment: There is another possibility for the return value of the doWork which is `Worker.Result.RETRY` maybe you are missing the RETRY value and since there is no throwable error you don't get exception. I am not really sure about that by the way.

Comment: @AlperenKantarcı I need only Failure status to return. No need for retry